# Hover transitions with absolute elements

Tags: html, css

I have an image with an absolutely positioned link centered on top of it. I have transition effects when the image is hovered over, but they are lost when the link is hovered over.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imagediv">
    <img src="#">
    <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imagediv img {
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.imagediv img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}

.imagediv a {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

How can I make it so my effects on image hover are retained on link hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS selector to trigger when the `.imagediv` is hovered not the `img` itself.

```
.imagediv img {
    transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.imagediv:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:hover` on the `imagediv`

```css
.imagediv {
  position: relative;               /*  added so link position relates to imagediv  */
}
.imagediv img {
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.imagediv:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}
.imagediv a {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagediv">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x100/f00">
    <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to switch the order of the `img` `text` elements, you could use the general sibling selector, but it only works with *folowing* siblings

```
a:hover ~ img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

```css
.imagediv img {
transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.imagediv img:hover{
transform: scale(1.2);
filter: grayscale(50%);
}

.imagediv a {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a:hover ~ img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagediv">
    <a href="#">Text</a>
    <img src="#">
</div>

.imagediv img {
transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.imagediv img:hover{
transform: scale(1.2);
filter: grayscale(50%);
}

.imagediv a {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to fix:

- You should move the `:hover` style to container.
- The container should be set to `relative` position, so that the `absolute` link can be centered inside, otherwise the offsets will be relative to the viewport.

```css
.imagediv {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.imagediv img {
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.imagediv:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}

.imagediv a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagediv">
  <img src="//unsplash.it/200">
  <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

If you need the entire block to be clickable, you can use flexbox.

```css
.imagediv {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.imagediv img {
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.imagediv:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}

.imagediv a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagediv">
  <img src="//unsplash.it/200">
  <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```